# Integral Units Question

Tags: calculus, unit-of-measure

$\textbf{Question:}$ An automobile accelerates from rest at $1+3\sqrt{t}$ mph/s for $9$ s.

What is its velocity after $9$ seconds?

My Answer Would Be the Following:

$a(t)=1+3t^{1/2}\cdot \frac{mi}{hr\cdot s}\cdot \frac{60 s}{1 min}\frac{60 min}{1 hr}=(1+3t^{1/2})\cdot 60^2 \frac{mi}{hr^2}$

$\implies v=(t+2t^{3/2})\cdot 60^2+c$ where $t$ is time in hours and $v$ is mph.

$\implies v=(t+2t^{3/2})\cdot 60^2$ again where $t$ is time in hours and $v$ is mph.

So, $v=(\frac{u}{60^2}+2(\frac{u}{60^2})^{3/2})\cdot 60^2$ where $u$ is time in seconds and $v$ is mph.

So,
\begin{align*}
v&=(\frac{9}{60^2}+2(\frac{9}{60^2})^{3/2})\cdot 60^2\\
&=(\frac{9}{60^2}+2(\frac{3}{60})^{3})\cdot 60^2\\
&=(\frac{9}{60^2}+2(\frac{27}{60^3}))\cdot 60^2\\
&=9+\frac{2\cdot 27}{60}\\
&=9+\frac{54}{60}\\
&= 9.9 \text{ mph}.\\
\end{align*}

The answer in my book is $63$ mph. So, what is wrong with this logic/what is the error?

Comment: I'm ... honestly not entirely sure myself. The arithmetic itself seems to hold so it must be something conceptual with the units I'm overlooking. I will note, however, that the text's answer matches simply calculating

$$\int_0^9 \Big( 1 + 3 \sqrt{t} \Big) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: You are mishandling the units.  Just consider a crude estimate: at time $t=4$ you are accelerating at $1+6=7$ mph/per sec.  Even if you imagine that you are at rest at $t=4$ and that acceleration isn't getting faster, you'd be at $7$ mph at $t=5$, $14$ mph at $t=6$, then $21$, ending at $35$ mph at $t=9$.  And this crude calculation is a dramatic underestimate.

Comment: Why am I mishandling the units then? When $t=4$, you get $7 mph/sec$ which you should convert to mi/hr^2 for this to make sense correct?

Comment: There is no reason to scale the function.  Saying $a(4)=7$ means that, at time $t=4$, you are accelerating by $7$ mph each second.  Thus, if you were at rest at $t=4$, then five seconds later, at $t=9$, you'd be moving at $35$ mph, assuming constant acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the acceleration function itself does not have a meaningful unit. We assume that $t$ is measured in seconds, but certainly $1$ has different units from $\sqrt t$ (in $\text{sec}^{1/2}$). So it does not make sense to do mechanical conversion from one unit system to another. When you started and gave the formula in terms of $\text{mi/hr}^2$, notice that $t$ is still in seconds, not in hours. But you cavalierly switched to $t$ in hours with no attention to the $\sqrt t$.

The problem should have specified that $t$ is measured in seconds, and you were intended just to integrate $a(t)$ *in seconds*, with the answer then being in mph.

Comment: Okay, so if $t$ was in seconds you would have $a=(1+3t^{1/2})(\frac{1}{60^2})$ converting $\frac{mi}{hr\cdot sec}$ to $\frac{mi}{sec^2}$. Is that not allowed then?

Comment: Sure. This doesn’t lead to any errors. This will give the same answer as we’ve suggested proceeding.

Comment: But then $v=\frac{1}{60^2}(t+2t^{3/2})$ and when $t=9$ seconds this isn't the answer though

Comment: Sure it is. Convert back to mph.

Comment: Omg, I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you! Makes sense now.

Comment: Sure! The moral of the story is that the original acceleration formula is not homogeneous and so you can’t change units and expect it to make sense. That said, your exercise should have said explicitly that $t$ is measured in seconds.